# Mic mute/Unmute Toggle is not working

Tags: autohotkey, nircmd

Trying to toggle Mute/Unmute  for my microphone on the latest windows 10 build but its not working

what I'm trying to do below in the code is toggle the mic and each time I do toggle the mic a notification should popup with the current state of the mic but its not working

```
F8::
    Run nircmd.exe mutesysvolume 2 microphone
    SoundGet, microphone_mute, Microphone, mute
    if (microphone_mute = "Off"){
        TrayTip MicState, ON
    } else(
        TrayTip MicState, OFF
    )
    Return
```

Comment: I don't know which program (Python?) you are using to program with. Have you tried GetMicState or GetMicState() SetMicState ?

Comment: This is autohotkey script + nircmd.exe , read tags on my post, this has nothing to do with python